# jQuery plugin for serializing XML to JSON

Tags: jquery, xml, json, jquery-plugins

What is the best jQuery plugin for serializing XML to JSON?

Comment: @Sinan Does it really matter for this question? I don't see the difference in this case. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Query XML to JSON Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) by Fyneworks.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try to use it right now, and basically, I'm quite satisfied with it. But I've noticed some issues. For example, if I have an array of the same elements in XML, and that array contains only one element, then the plugin considers this as an object, not as an array with one element. It would be convenient to have an ability to handle such cases explicitly (i.e. specify element name which should be considered as an array).

Comment: It seems that you can choose whether or not to have single-element arrays converted to objects or not. Just pass "true" as second argument, and it will keep all as arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

Comment: Please, see comment to @Adnan's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try [XML Objectifier](http://www.terracoder.com/index.php/xml-objectifier).

Comment: niutech, aside from the abstraction layer (which is a great concept) what features does XML Objectifier have that make it better than xml2json?