# jQuery XML parsing - Getting attribute values

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I am getting this following xml response after sending requests through Ajax, so i want to parse this following **xml** data using **jQuery** to get the specific attribute values.

```
<Room1>
            <Node Name='Scene1' Text='Morning'/>
            <Node Name='Scene2' Text='Leaving'/>
            <Node Name='Scene3' Text='Morning'/>
            <Node Name='Scene4' Text='Entertainment'/>
            <Node Name='Scene5' Text='Party'/>
            <Node Name='Scene6' Text='s6'/>
            <Node Name='Scene7' Text='Watch TV'/>
            <Node Name='Scene8' Text='Watch Movie'/>
            <Node Name='Scene9' Text='TV on Screen'/>
            <Node Name='Scene10' Text='Movie on Screen'/>
            <Node Name='Scene11' Text='Leaving Room'/>
</Room1>
```

I want to get the values of attributes **Name** and **Text**. The following code is what i have tried,

```
 $.ajax({
            method : "GET",
            url    :  "controller/Controller.php",
            data   : "myData=Room1",
            success:function(response){
                    var xml = response;

                    $(xml).find('Room1').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('Node').each(function(){
                            console.log($(this).attr('Name'));
                        });
                    });
                }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you convert the whole xml into json, and then you can use json as you use objects in jquery.

[jQuery plugin for serializing XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079352/jquery-plugin-for-serializing-xml-to-json)

e.g to get to name and text attribute, all you would do is:

$.each(jsonObject, function(index) { console.log($(this).name) }

Comment: I have tried this way before but i haven't find such a nice plugin to do it. Thanks Neeraj, it works for me.